# What is the name of this kind of layout?

Tags: website-design, layout

Please visit this site: http://www.visitheritage.com/

Can someone tell me in which category does that kind of website layout belong?
Or in other words, how you simply call it?

I notice that this kind of layout usually have:

1. Drop down menu navigation
2. Image slider (very big) & contains hyperlink
3. 3-4 additional navigation links which usually contains images and little text
4. Very minimalist footer that only contains copyright notice, links to social media, & faq or disclaimer hyperlink.

I usually see this kind of layout in professional organization's website..

Btw I hope I am not in the wrong forum. Let me know if otherwise.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there really is a name for this kind of layout, the broad style is [web 2.0](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/web-design/web-2-0-design-style-guide/). If you're looking for a template take a look at [themeforest](http://www.themeforest.com) they have many similar designs available for purchase.